# Azure release gates api version 2018-05-05 not showing up results

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-monitoring

I am trying to use a pre-deployment gate(Query Azure Monitor alerts) in release pipeline. Also I am trying to fetch the alerts since last 30d, but the api version  2018-05-05 is not populating the result. But if I have the api version  to 2019-03-01 all alerts are shown.

Problem is the Query Azure Monitor alerts gate is using the api version 2018-05-05, Is there any way to change this inside gate and use the new api version 2019-03-01 ?

Please let me know if there is any other way to get the alerts in gates.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is there any way to change this inside gate and use the new api version 2019-03-01 ?

Sorry for any inconvenience.

I am afraid there is no such way to change the inside gate to use the new api version `2019-03-01`. Since it is a built-in gates, we could not modify its source code or customize it to extend.

To resolve this issue, you could submit this request on the github about this task:

https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues

Note: I could not find the API version 2019-03-01, just [2018-05-05](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall), you could provide the link for 2019-03-01 when you submit the request.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I have submitted the request.
https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/12683

I have also mentioned the steps to get API version 2019-03-01

Comment: @KuljeetSingh, Thank you for helping us build a better Azure DevOps. I will continue to pay attention to that thread.