# Azure API 'get all alerts" no value

Tags: azure, azure-powershell, azure-api-management, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

I want to get all my alerts that are triggert with azure monitor.
I use the Azure documentation but I don't get any alerts.
I get status 200 but no alerts.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/monitor/alertsmanagement/alerts/getall

Any suggestions?

Comment: I suppose you used the wrong API, please show the screenhsot like this https://i.stack.imgur.com/dpXSZ.png in your resource group of the alerts, select the `Show hidden types` option.

Comment: I want to view the alerts that are triggerd. From the all alert page.3 Where there is a monitor condition, alert state,...

Comment: Change the api version to 2019-03-01 and try again.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61184621/azure-release-gates-api-version-2018-05-05-not-showing-up-results

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the api version to 2019-03-01 and try again.